# Coinpaprika reached maximum request limit error

Tags: python

I'm using Coinpaprika python client and I got this error :

```
 coinpaprika.exceptions.CoinpaprikaAPIException:
 CoinpaprikaAPIException(status_code: 429):
 you have reached maximum request limit
```

Comment: https://api.coinpaprika.com/#section/Rate-limit

Answer (score -1):

The error solved by unistalling the package and reinstall it:

```
pip uninstall coinpaprika 
pip install coinpaprika
```

Comment: You reached the rate limit of the API. Most likely the error resolved with the **time** it took to reinstall.

Comment: No it was not related to the time elapsed because at same time I could get the result without error by direct HttpGet call to the API. It was related to client id of the python client that resolved by reinstall.

Comment: a) the error message and code indicate a rate limit hit b) uninstalling and installing with `pip` does not reset any ID. You have been mislead by the short timeframe of the rate limit.